# Set Iterators in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, set, std

Can iterator be subtracted for set stl in c++? Like it is possible in vector...

```
int32_t main()
{
    set<int> s = {1, 3, 0, 23};
    vector<int> v = {1, 3, 0, 23};

    int vind = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 1) - v.begin(); //This is ok with no error

    int sind = find(s.begin(), s.end(), 1) - s.begin();  //But this gives error
    cout<<vind <<" " << sind;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not being able to figure out the reason. Why it is not possible in set??

Comment: Because given the nature of set iterators subtraction cannot be implemented efficiently. You can use the std::distance function. `sind = std::distance(find(s.begin(), s.end(), 1), s.begin());` but be aware that calling this function will take time proportional to the index returned. In other words it's a linear time operation, not a constant time operation.

Comment: @Evg Thanks I've made the same mistake on the few occaisions I've had to use that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator of `std::set` is [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which doesn't support `operator-` between iterators. (The iterator of `std::vector` is [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which supports that.)

You can use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) instead. (Note that the complexity is linear for InputIterator including BidirectionalIterator.)

```
int sind = std::distance(s.begin(), find(s.begin(), s.end(), 1));
```